# Generating an unordered list from javascript node objects

Tags: javascript, tree

I have written the following codes, the purpose of these codes is to generate an `<ul>` from some javascript Node objects:

```
<html>

<body>
<div id='content'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>

            function node(name,parent){
                this.name=name;
                this.parent=parent;
                this.level=function(){
                    if(this.parent==null)
                        return 0;
                    return this.parent.level()+1;                    
                }
                this.childs=new Array();
            }

            //create a rootNode, having no parent
            var rootNode=new node('AAA',null);

            //create node1 and add it to the child of rootNode
            var node1=new node('BBB',rootNode);
            rootNode.childs.push(node1);

            //create node2 and add it to the child of rootNode
            var node2=new node('CCC',rootNode);
            rootNode.childs.push(node2);

            //create node3 and add it to the child of node1
            var node3=new node('DDD',node1);
            node1.childs.push(node3);

            //create node4 and add it to the child of node1
            var node4=new node('EEE',node1);
            node1.childs.push(node4);

            //create node5 and add it to the child of node2
            var node5=new node('FFF',node2);
            node2.childs.push(node5);

            function getTreeHTML(node,html){

                if(node.level()==0)
                    html+='<ul>';

                html+='<li>';
                html+=node.name;
                if(node.childs.length > 0){
                    html+='<ul>';
                    for(var i in node.childs){
                        html+=getTreeHTML(node.childs[i],html);
                    }
                    html+='</ul>';
                }
                html+='</li>';

                if(node.level()==0)
                    html+='</ul>';
                return html;
            }

            var treeHTML=getTreeHTML(rootNode,'');
            document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=treeHTML;
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Under rootNode, there are two immediate child nodes, for these two child nodes, one of them should have two <strike>childs</strike> children and another should have one child. I suspect there is a logical bug in the `getTreeHTML()` function but I just can't figure out what it is, feel free to paste the codes on http://htmledit.squarefree.com/, then you can quickly see what I mean.

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: FYI, plural of child is children, not childs :)

Comment: @Psytronic Thanks. I will use children next time. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
html+=getTreeHTML(node.childs[i],html);
```

You're ending up *adding to* the HTML string twice, because within the function you append to the HTML string passed in, but then you use an append operation with what it returns as well. If you change it to either of these, it works fine:

```
html=getTreeHTML(node.childs[i],html);
html+=getTreeHTML(node.childs[i],'');
```

---

**Off-topic**: Some suggestions/recommendations/observations if you're interested; none of the below is meant to be critical, only helpful:

1. Rather than concatenating strings, it generally works out faster if you build up a bunch of strings in an Array and then use a `join('')` to put them all together into one string when you're done.
2. Standard practice (which you're free to ignore!) is to make constructor functions like `node` initially capped (`Node`), to differentiate them from non-constructor functions.
3. Each of your `node` objects will get its own *copy* of the `level` function, which isn't necessary in your code. They can all share *one* `level` function, like this:

   ```
   function node(name,parent){
       this.name=name;
       this.parent=parent;
       this.childs=new Array();
   }
   node.prototype.level = function() {
       if(this.parent==null)
           return 0;
       return this.parent.level()+1;                    
   }
   ```
4. In English, the plural of "child" is "children" (it's irregular).
5. Using `for..in` to loop through array indexes, as in your `for(var i in node.childs){`, is delicate and technically incorrect unless you take a couple of precautions in the loop; it will fail if you do anything interesting with your arrays like add more meta-data to them (arrays are just objects, you can add arbitrary properties to them; and libraries sometimes add properties to `Array.prototype` to smooth out browser differences, which will muck up a naive `for..in` loop). Details here: [*Myths and realities of `for..in`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)
6. You can write `this.childs=new Array();` as `this.childs=[];` if you like; they have exactly the same effect.
7. Regardless of where you put your `var` statement in your code, it takes effect at the top of the function (or the top of the global scope, if the `var` is global). I think I'm a bit on my own with this, but I don't like having my code be a bit misleading to code maintainers, so I always put the `var`s up top. More here [*Poor misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html). So for instance:

   ```
   // This series of statements
   doSomething();
   doSomethingElse();
   var a = new Foo();
   doAnotherThing();


   // ...is *exactly* identical to:
   var a;
   doSomething();
   doSomethingElse();
   a = new Foo();
   doAnotherThing();
   ```
8. Recommend a function on `node` that creates a child and hooks it up, so you avoid the possibility of the `parent` being set but then the child added to the wrong `childs` array (or not added at all).
9. Using `null` to mean "no parent" is fine, but `undefined` is actually a bit easier to work with.
10. You can use the power of [*JavaScript's Curiously-Powerful OR Operator (||)*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html) in some places. You see this a *lot* in JavaScript code. `if` statements are *totally* fine, but I thought it worth mentioning because it's such common practice.
11. Braces really are your friends, even when they're not necessary.

Taking all of that and a couple of minor things together:

```
var rootNode, node1, node2;

function Node(name, parent){
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent; // undefined if none
    this.children = [];
}
Node.prototype.level = function(){
    return this.parent ? this.parent.level() + 1 : 0;
};
Node.prototype.addChild = function(name) {
    var child;

    child = new Node(name, this);
    this.children.push(child);
    return child;
};

//create a rootNode, having no parent
rootNode = new Node('AAA');

//create node1 and add it to the child of rootNode
node1 = rootNode.addChild('BBB');

//create node2 and add it to the child of rootNode
node2 = rootNode.addChild('CCC');

//create node3 and add it to the child of node1
node1.addChild('DDD');

//create node4 and add it to the child of node1
node1.addChild('EEE');

//create node5 and add it to the child of node2
node2.addChild('FFF');

function getTreeHTML(node, html) {
    var i;

    html = html || []; // In case they don't give it

    if(node.level()==0) {
        html.push('<ul>');
    }

    html.push('<li>');
    html.push(node.name);
    if (node.children.length > 0) {
        html.push('<ul>');
        for (i = 0; i < node.children.length; ++i) {
            getTreeHTML(node.children[i], html);
        }
        html.push('</ul>');
    }
    html.push('</li>');

    if (node.level() == 0) {
        html.push('</ul>');
    }

    return html;
}

var treeHTML = getTreeHTML(rootNode).join('');
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=treeHTML;
```

Comment: Or remove the `html`-parameter completely, construct the html into a local variable and returning that. It would be somewhat "cleaner".

Comment: On a different issue, shouldn't the code be html+=getTreeHTML(i,''); and not html+=getTreeHTML(node.childs[i],'');
I mean, each i will be a node type itself, so why are we using i as an index. I am little bit confused here.

Comment: @Gunner: No, the code's right. `for..in` doesn't loop through the array entries, it loops through the property *names* (in this case, array *indexes*) of the object. So `i` will be `0`, then `1`, etc.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks for answer and all the self tagged off-topic comments. I wish I could up vote your post a second time :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. I (possibly some other people) have learnt a lot from you.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder It's really amazing to get an answer like this, which is very very informative. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `html` parameter all together:

```
function getTreeHTML(node){
    var html = "";
    if(node.level()==0)
        html+='<ul>';

    html+='<li>';
    html+=node.name;
    if(node.childs.length > 0){
        html+='<ul>';
        for(var i in node.childs){
            html+=getTreeHTML(node.childs[i]);
        }
        html+='</ul>';
    }
    html+='</li>';

    if(node.level()==0)
        html+='</ul>';
    return html;
}
```

Comment: There's a logical bug in my brain. Thanks for your answer, it's a useful one.

Comment: I'd retain it, but make it an array, so you get the ability to build everything up in an array and then do a `join('')` at the end, which is faster on nearly every (possibly every) JavaScript implementation I've run into than string concatenation. FWIW.

Comment: @T.J indeed, I'd also convert the whole thing to Factory Design pattern, and make GetTreeHtml a function of the Node object ;)